# How can I salvage the walls after painting over wallpaper?

Tags: paint, wallpaper

So I moved into our house and the lady before me had faux finished the walls. I used latex paint and painted over everything. Ah, a fresh coat of paint.... NOPE! Well, she had painted over wallpaper and now its wrinkled in the corners and there are seams everywhere. Any suggestions other than taking it all down? It's everywhere, kitchen, breakfast area, living room and formal living room. I've thought of Venetian plaster but it just seems like it will continue to make it heavy. I need help!

Comment: The only proper answer is to take down the wall paper--which, alas, may be much harder to do now that it's painted. May be easier to just put up new sheetrock.

Comment: @DA01 sounds like an answer (even if it is an unwelcome one).

Comment: I think we need several good pictures before we can make a call.

Answer (score 2):

Rent wall-paper steamers to remove the wall paper. Unfortunately, the latex paint will make it harder. You need to find a way to allow the steam to penetrate the latex. Use a scraper to scrape the paint, but not through the paper, so you don't damage the underlying wall surface. I've used rasps, cheese graters, etc. Just be careful you don't damage the walls too much!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably from someone who upvoted DA01's comment. You answered the OP, who wished to save the drywall, correctly. However, that comment is the *right* answer (it's the only option I'd submit).

Comment: Steamer is the way to go. OP states that the wallpaper is wrinkled and there are many seams, so I think a steamer will take it down no problem.

Comment: Be prepared to do drywall re-taping because those seams are going to need it and the steam will lift drywall tape too.

Comment: There is a tool called a "Paper Tiger" that will make small puncture holes in wallpaper to make steaming easier.